# Speed up text processing in R

Tags: performance, r, optimization, text

I am working on optimizing a piece of software and the most expensive lines are the text processing lines of code. By taking apart the program and commenting certain sections out, I have found out that a little argument in an if-statement is causing most of the bottleneck in the program. In the statement it asks if

```
allele1 %in% rownames(seqMat)
```

is true, and if so the statements that follow will be called. This if statement is looped thousands of times and causes the program to slow down significantly. My question is, how can that statement be changed to help speed up the program?

Comment: Try `any(alllel1 == rownames(seqMat))`

Comment: You could call `%in%` once for all alleles before the loop, and store  its output (a vector of booleans) for reuse inside the loop. (That's assuming your loop goes over alleles)

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info?  Why is it looped so many times?  Is there a list of allele's checked or is seqMat one of many files?

Comment: Also, use `Rprof` next time.  Much better than commenting and uncommenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call `%in%` only once for all your alleles and store its output for reuse inside the loop. Here is a proof of concept:

```
a <- sample(1:1000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
b <- -1000:1000

system.time({
    stored <- a %in% b
    for (i in seq_along(a))
        stored[i]
}) 
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.056   0.001   0.056 

system.time({
    for (i in seq_along(a))
        a[i] %in% b
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.634   0.374   3.957
```

Also, Hadley's suggestion of using `any` and `==` is not that big of an improvement:

```
system.time({
    for (i in seq_along(a))
        any(a[i] == b)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.661   0.164   1.835
```

Comment: I have some variables that are reallocated in the for loop as an ith row in column x, i.e. my allele1 variable is reallocated in each iteration of the loop. This complicates things a little further.